# Get Getdate in Entity Frame work 2013

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm new to `Entity Framework`.

How can I get server date (`get date`) in `Entity Framework`? (I'm using `Visual Studio 2013`).

I tried for **`SqlFunction.GetDate()`**. Other than this, is there any other method to get the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to be more precise in your questions. It would be useful for us to know, what you want to achieve to propose you the simplest way.

To get date directly from server, you should use ExecuteQuery() method and call SQL method. In your context add method like this:

```
public DateTime GetDate()
{
    return ExecuteQuery<DateTime>("SELECT GETDATE()").First();
}
```

where

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

is raw T-SQL method.

To just have a date of addition entity the simplest way is to call method on the level of your app. For this purpose add property to one of your entity:

```
public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
```

When you'll be adding new entity invoke (db means context object):

```
db.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
```

You will get current date thanks to these operations. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try [DbFunctions.CreateDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.createdatetime%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)